# Force leave on bad faith is illegal, what does bad faith mean?

Tags: labor-law, philippines

This is question about Philippines labor law.

Force leave or floating status is putting an employee for a specific amount of time away from work because of circumstances like no project or disaster.

However, this can be illegal if an employee is put on force leave for:

1. More than 6 months. Which basically the employee is terminated and will be given severance pay.
2. Force leave done in bad faith.

So my question is, what would be characterize as bad faith?

Comment: Probably with an intent not to rehire. Will have to look for citations.

Comment: @ohwilleke if it is in court, how would you prove it?

Comment: Circumstantial evidence (e.g. hiring others, announcing plans not to reopen in news reports, a history of doing the same thing), or smoking gun statements (e.g. someone hits "reply all" on a damaging email, or tells a friend in a bar who is subpoenaed and testifies truthfully).